# Progressive union of a large number of multiband rasters in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, union

I am deriving multiband rasters from airborne lidar imagery, and loading these into PostGIS along with associated metadata. Raster cell values are counts of certain point classes over a series of vertical strata. Each input raster is 200 x 200 cells (with slight variation) and has 160 bands. Rasters from adjacent images overlap slightly. Stitching them together with ST_Union and the 'SUM' option works perfectly when dealing with small numbers of rasters, but I've been stuck for a while on how to scale this up to the many thousands to be processed without things slowing to a crawl. I am relatively new to PostGIS, so I'm looking for advice about table design and query structure (detailed below).

The current design involves two raster tables. The first table (A) holds rasters as derived from each lidar image, with no regard to overlap. Tile sizes in this table are taken from the inputs and can vary slightly. The second table (U) holds a unioned version of the same data with a uniform 100x100 tile size. This duplication of data across two tables is motivated by the need to correct and re-import data when problems are identified in individual source LiDAR images, something that occurs commonly.

Importing each new raster involves the following steps:

1. Load raster into A. Tile size is taken from input and can vary between recs.
2. Identify any 100x100 raster tiles in U that overlap the new raster in A.
3. In a temp table (T), union (SUM) the new raster with the overlapping tiles from U.
4. Delete the overlapping tiles from table U.
5. Insert the unioned data from T into B.

This seems to work but slows to a snail's pace as the number of rasters grows. There is a spatial index on table U and the number of overlapping rasters cannot be more than a few by definition, so I expected the running time for each iteration of the above steps to be more or less constant. Obviously I'm missing something.

As an experiment, I imported larger batches of rasters (several hundred) into table A and then attempted to union these in one go, but after more than 12 hours this had still not completed.

The initial processing of the lidar images and subsequent import into PostGIS is done via R using custom written R packages. The steps detailed above are performed by sending SQL from R to PG. I've experimented with running the same queries via psql but performance appears identical, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with R *per se*, more likely a problem with my SQL code.

Here's the code:

```
-- Identify existing rasters that overlap the new data
create or replace view mgazone56.overlaps as
  select pcu.rid from
    mgazone56.point_counts_union as pcu, mgazone56.tmp_load as tl
    where st_intersects(pcu.rast, tl.rast);

create table if not exists mgazone56.tmp_union (rast raster);

truncate table mgazone56.tmp_union;

-- Union overlapping rasters with new data, summing overlap values
insert into mgazone56.tmp_union
  select ST_Union(r.rast, 'SUM') as rast from
    (select rast from mgazone56.point_counts_union
       where rid in (select rid from mgazone56.overlaps)
     union all
     select rast from mgazone56.tmp_load) as r;

-- Delete overlapping rasters from main table
delete from mgazone56.point_counts_union
  where rid in (select rid from mgazone56.overlaps);

-- Insert updated data
select DropRasterConstraints('mgazone56'::name, 'point_counts_union'::name, 'rast'::name);

insert into mgazone56.point_counts_union (rast)
  select ST_Tile(rast, 100, 100) as raster
  from mgazone56.tmp_union;

select AddRasterConstraints('mgazone56'::name, 'point_counts_union'::name, 'rast'::name);

-- Delete records from the temporary tables
truncate table mgazone56.tmp_load;
truncate table mgazone56.tmp_union;
```